# WhenEvent for space variable

Tags: equation-solving

Can I use WhenEvent for space variable? For example

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == k + D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t]},
  {u}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}];
```

The parameter `k` takes the value `k0` if `x < 5` and the value `k1` if `x > 5` with the constraint that u[t,x=5-]=u[t,x=5+]  (continuity of `U` at the discontinuity `x == 5`).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

`Piecewise` seems to accomplish what you want.  I don't think `WhenEvent` can be used, but I'm not completely sure.

```
k[x_] := Piecewise[{{2, x < 5}, {-1, x > 5}}];

{sol} = NDSolve[
  {D[u[t, x], t] == k[x] + D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == 0, u[t, 0] == Sin[t]},
  {u}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization"->{"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints"->100}}];
```

There is a warning

> NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>

```
Plot3D[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can also use `Method -> "FiniteElement"`, but it gives the warning

> NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help. >>

Residuals may be examined and the solution judged with the following:

```
Plot3D[D[u[t, x], t] == k[x] + D[u[t, x], x, x] /. Equal -> Subtract /. sol // Evaluate,
 {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]

Plot[u[t, 0] == Sin[t] /. Equal -> Subtract /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[u[0, x] /. sol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}]
```